# Getting a file with hash (#) in path by curl

Tags: bash, url, curl

I want to use `curl` (v 7.22.0) to download some files from a server, where they name directories like `report#1`, `report#2`, etc. So i tried...

```
curl sftp://sftp.example.com/report#1/main.png -u login:pass -o tmp.txt
```

...but `curl` gives me *"no such file or directory"*. It probably thinks the hash is a fragment identifier (e. g. web page anchor) and therefore looks at URL `sftp://sftp.example.com/report` instead.

Is there a way how to escape a hash sign, so it is recognized as a part of file path? (Quoting/escaping doesn't help.)

Comment: You probably have to escape the `#` --> `curl http://...\#...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

Replace in URL `#` with `%23`.